# extraction of data in [a, b, c] and splitting them with comma

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $str = "a, [b,c,d], k , [p,q,r], k, [x,y,z]";
```

I want to remove the commas in between `[]` so that I would be getting output as :

```
"a, [b c d], k , [p q r], k, [x y z]"
```

I have tried extracting data between `[]` but was not able to.

Is this possible ?

Thanks and Regards,

Amar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the square brackets are always paired correctly and there's no escaping mechanism, you can just remove all commas followed by `]` when there's no `[` in between:

```
$str =~ s/,(?=[^\[]*\])/ /g;
```

It uses the "look-ahead" assertion, i.e. `(?=...)`, which contains `[^\[]*`, i.e. character class that contains anything but `[`, repeated zero or more times, followed by a `]`. So, it only matches when a comma is followed by any number of non-`[` characters followed by a `]`, which means it must be inside square brackets.

Comment: hi sir could you please elaborate this has worked for me but i dinn't understand regex expression